# Reverse a string of characters

Tags: python, python-3.x

I tried this code but I don't know how input the characters one per line and how to stop the input sequence with the character 0.

```py
def reverse(string):
    if len(string) == 0:
        return string
    else:
        return reverse(string[1:]) + string[0]
a = str(input())
print(reverse(a))
```

Comment: Can you be more clear on what you want here? I'm not sure what your actual problem is.

Comment: Is doing it recursively required or can you just use a oneliner?

Comment: Your code snippet works...What exactly is the problem?

Comment: I need an input one per line and the input sequence with this code dosen't stop with 0. I want the program stops when input value is 0.

Answer (score 2):

In python you can usually reverse an iterable with `[::-1]`.
It should work on strings as well, I guess. So: `'hello'[::-1]` gives `'olleh'`.